# Difference between ANDing with bitwise shift and hex values

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitwise-and

If I want to set bit 2 of a value to `0`, what's the difference between the two following:

```
value = value & (1<<2);
value = value & 0x2;
```

Comment: The difference is that they set different bits. `(1 << 2) == 0x4` Considering closing as a typo.

Comment: ah and i thought i understood it..

Comment: How are you numbering your bits? I.e. is the first bit 0 or 1?

Answer (score 4):

When using a bitwise AND, you clear *all* bits not set in the mask.  So you're actually only retaining one bit.  If you only want to clear one, set all bits to 1 *except* the one you want.  You can use the the `~` operator to invert all bits in your mask as follows:

```
value = value & ~(1<<2);
value = value & ~(0x2);
```

That said, These two statements clear different bits.  In the first case , `1<<2` evaluates to 4, i.e. `00000100` or `0x04`.  In the second case, `0x2` is `00000010`.  Their inversions are `11111011` and `11111101` respectively.

Comment: The question says "set to `0`", not just "set".

Comment: @melpomene Good catch.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

**Formal answer**

Strictly speaking, if you are working with [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) then first form `value = value & (1<<2);`, which is equal to (pseudo, or using GNU extension, code that allows binary constants) `value = value & 0b100;` will set to `0` **all bits except bit 2** and the second form `value = value & 0x2;` (or `value = value & 0b10;`) will set to `0` **all bits except bit 1**. So finally second form will do what you want - set to `0` bit 2 (together with many other bits, but who cares if we take your question exactly as it written?).
Please note that if you are in MSB world than both of them will set to `0` bit 2

**Informal answer**

If, despite how you phrased you question, you actually wanted to know if there is difference between constant expression that uses shift operation and just constant literal then answer is no, there is no difference - compiler will evaluate `expression (1<<2)` as `4` at compile time

And how to correctly set just one bit to `0` is described in dbush's answer

Comment: The code in the question uses `0x2`, not `4`.

Comment: @melpomene yes, that is already pointed by others, I wanted to address actual question about difference between constant expression with shift and a constant